# Implement a Comparator to sort list of integers on the basis of number of '5' digits integers contain

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, logic, comparator

I have a list of integers which needs to be sorted on the basis of number of digit 5 they contain. I have to implement comparator interface for it.

**Note(case): If two numbers have same number of '5' or they don't contain '5' then they should be in ascending order.**

Example: 525,155,555,15,5555

Output: 15,155,525,555,5555

Explanation:

15 has one '5' digit

155 has two '5' digits

525 has two '5' digits

555 has three digits

5555 has four '5' digits.

based on this they should be sorted.

**Note: 525 and 155 both have same number of '5' digits so they are in ascending order.**

My code is partially working, It is not sorting numbers with same numbers of '5' digit.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ClassComparable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer arr[] = {155,85555,15, 405, 555, 510, 20, 150, 50, 85, 5505, 555, 959};
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
        System.out.println("before ="+list);

        list.sort(new ClassComparable().new NumberOfFivesComparator());
        System.out.println("after="+list);

    }

    class NumberOfFivesComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Integer t2, Integer t1) {
            int countInT1 = 0;
            int countInT2 = 0;

            while (t2 != 0) {

                if (t2 % 10 == 5) {
                    countInT2++;
                }
                t2 = t2 / 10;
            }
            while (t1 != 0) {
                if (t1 % 10 == 5) {
                    countInT1++;
                }
                t1= t1 / 10;
            }

            if(countInT1<countInT2) return 1;
           if (countInT1>countInT2) return -1;
           
           //if same number of '5's or no '5's are there then they must have ascending order, //help!!!!!!!!!!!!
            if(t1<t2) return 1;
            if (t1>t2) return -1;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

> before =[155, 85555, 15, 405, 555, 510, 20, 150, 50, 85, 5505,555,959]

> after=[20, 15, 405, 510, 150, 50, 85, 959, 155, 555, 5505, 555,85555]

**> Error=[15, 405, 510, 150, 50, 85, 959] have one '5' digits but they are not in ascending order. same error with [555, 5505, 555].**

> expected out put= [20,15,50,85,150,405,510,959,155,555,555,5505,85555]

Comment: Note: By declaring `static class NumberOfFivesComparator`, you can save the extra `new ClassComparable()` when creating an instance of it.

Comment: @Izruo you can also completely avoid an extra class by just using a method reference such as `list.sort(Scratch::compare);`, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You're counting the 5s incorrectly.

If your treat the number as a `String` and count the 5s in like this:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer arr[] = {155,85555,15, 405, 555, 510, 20, 150, 50, 85, 5505, 555, 959};
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
        System.out.println("before ="+list);
        list.sort(Scratch::compare);
        System.out.println("after="+list);
    }
    public static int compare(Integer t2, Integer t1) {
        long countInT1 = t1.toString().chars().filter(c -> c=='5').count();
        long countInT2 = t2.toString().chars().filter(c -> c=='5').count();
        if(countInT1<countInT2) return 1;
        if(countInT1>countInT2) return -1;
        if(t1<t2) return 1;
        if(t1>t2) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

it prints

```
before =[155, 85555, 15, 405, 555, 510, 20, 150, 50, 85, 5505, 555, 959]
after=[20, 15, 50, 85, 150, 405, 510, 959, 155, 555, 555, 5505, 85555]
```

Comment: sorry your ans is wrong. number with same 5s should be in ascending order.

Comment: @CodingDevil I agree, i copied the wrong output. The code works correctly.

Comment: but why my code is not working? in my code 5s are counted in correct way.

Comment: @CodingDevil see Izruo explanation below

Comment: I also edited my answer to demonstrate how to avoid a whole extra `Comparator` class.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing the integer values `t1` and `t2` in `NumberOfFivesComparator.compare`, both values are `0` due to the algorithm done before.

```
while (t2 != 0) {
    if (t2 % 10 == 5) {
        countInT2++;
    }
    t2 = t2 / 10;
}
```

This loop will only exit when `t2=0`, so after both loops have completed, both `t1` and `t2` will be `0`, thus it will not affect the following sort. In other words, the method returns `0` for any two numbers, that have the same number of `5`s.

To fix this, either use a different method to calculate the number of `5`s, as f1sh suggested, or use temporary variables for the algorithm.

```
for (int t2temp = t2; t2temp != 0;) {
    if (t2temp % 10 == 5) {
        countInT2++;
    }
    t2temp = t2temp / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it just count the characters, it works fine so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer arr[] = {155,85555,15, 405, 555, 510, 20, 150, 50, 85, 5505, 555, 959};
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
    System.out.println("before ="+list);

    list.sort((o1, o2) -> {
        long c1 = getCounted5sOfInteger(o1);
        long c2 = getCounted5sOfInteger(o2);
        if (c1 != c2) {
            return Long.compare(c1, c2);
        } else {
            return Long.compare(o1, o2);
        }
    });
    System.out.println("after="+list);
}

private static long getCounted5sOfInteger(int i) {
    return String.valueOf(i).chars().filter(c -> c == '5').count();
}
```

**Output:**

```
before =[155, 85555, 15, 405, 555, 510, 20, 150, 50, 85, 5505, 555, 959]

after=[20, 15, 50, 85, 150, 405, 510, 959, 155, 555, 555, 5505, 85555]
```

Comment: Hi, Thx for solution. what are you doing in below snippet?  if (c1 != c2) {
            return Long.compare(c1, c2);
        } else {
            return Long.compare(o1, o2);
        }

Comment: I checked weather the two variables (counted 5s) are the same, if they are the are sorted in ascending order, if not I compared them by the counted 5s.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach it.

First, create  a lambda  to count the fives. This also caters to negative numbers in the list.

```
Function<Integer, Integer> countFives = s -> {
    int count = 0;
    s = Math.abs(s);
    while (s != 0) {
        int k = s % 10;
        if (k == 5) {
            count++;
        }
        s /= 10;
    }
    return count;
};
```

You could use the above function in a comparator directly.  But I would create a map where the keys are the numbers and the values are the counts.  This way, the counting of the fives is only done once for each value vs multiple times in a comparator.  For small lists though it doesn't really matter.  The lookup overhead of a map is minimal.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> counts =
        list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(n -> n,
                countFives, (dup, n) -> n));
```

Now define the comparator. First compare on the count and if equal, then on the actual numbers.

```
Comparator<Integer> comp = (a, b) -> {
    int v = Integer.compare(counts.get(a), counts.get(b));
    return v == 0 ? Integer.compare(a, b) : v;
};
```

Here is an example

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(-525, 155, 555, 15, 5, 15, -15, -5555));
list.sort(comp);
System.out.println(list);
```

prints

```
[-15, 5, 15, 15, -525, 155, 555, -5555]
```

Here is how the comparator might look without the map being used.

```
Comparator<Integer> comp = (a, b) -> {
    int ac = countFives.apply(a);
    int bc = countFives.apply(b);
    int v = Integer.compare(ac,bc);
    return v == 0 ? Integer.compare(a, b) : v;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a simpler chained comparator should be created using `Comparator::comparingInt` and `Comparator::thenComparing`, where the former part compares by the count of 5 and the latter compares the numbers themselves.

Counting of fives may be implemented for example by removing all non-5 characters from the string representation and getting the length of the remaining string:

```java
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(-1455, 525, 155, 555, 15, 5555, -15);

Comparator<Integer> by5countAndValue = Comparator.<Integer>comparingInt(
    x -> String.valueOf(x).replaceAll("[^5]", "").length()
).thenComparing(Function.identity());// or .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());

list.sort(by5countAndValue);
// -> [-15, 15, -1455, 155, 525, 555, 5555]
```

---

In case the string-based solution is considered a cheat trick, a recursive function to count the fives may be implemented and invoked:

```java
// class MyClass
private static int count5(Integer n) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(n)
        .map(Math::abs)
        .map(x -> count(x, 5))
        .orElse(0);
}

private static int count(int n, int digit) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return n == digit ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return (n % 10 == digit ? 1 : 0) + count(n / 10, digit);
}
```

building the comparator:

```java
Comparator<Integer> by5countAndValue = Comparator
        .<Integer>comparingInt(MyClass::count5)
        .thenComparing(x -> x);
```